# I can not prove that ((m xor a) xor (m and a))= (m or a)

Tags: boolean

I can not prove that ((m xor a) xor (m and a))= (m or a)

The truth table shows that they are, but I can't prove it using boolean algebra.
Can you guys help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OR: m+a
AND: m*a
XOR: [NOT(m) * a] + [m * NOT(a)]

`[(m OR a) XOR (m AND a)] = [(m+a) XOR ( m*a)]=`
`= [NOT(m+a) * m * a] + [(m+a) * NOT(m*a)]=`
`= [NOT(m) * NOT(a) * m * a] + [(m+a) * (NOT(m) + NOT(a))]=`
`= [NOT(m) * NOT(a) * a * m] + a * NOT(a) + a * NOT(m) + m * NOT(a) + m * NOT(m) =`
`= 0 + 0 + a * NOT(m) + m * NOT(a) + 0 =`
`= a * NOT(m) + m * NOT(a) = m XOR a`